# Capturing non-missing values row wise and storing it in new variables

Tags: stata, stata-macros

My dataset contains multiple variables called `avar_1` to `bvar_10` referring to the history of an individual. For some reasons, the history is not always complete and there are some "gaps" (e.g. `avar_1` and `avar_4` are non-missing, but `avar_2` and `avar_3` are missing). For each individual, I want to store the first non-missing value in a new variable called `var1` the second non-missing in `var2` etc, so that I have a history without missing values.

I've tried the following code

```
local x=1
foreach wave in a b {
    forval i=1/10 {
        capture drop var`x' 
        generate var`x'=.
        capture replace var`x'=`wave'var`i' if !mi(`wave'`var'`i')
        if (!mi(var`x')) {
            local x=1+`x'
            }
    }
}
```

`var1` is generated properly but `var2` only contains missings and following variables are not generated. However, I `set trace on` and saw that the `var2` is actually replaced for all variables from `avar_1` to `bvar_10`.

My guess is that the `local x` is not correctly updated as its value change for the whole dataset but should be different for each observation.

Is that the problem and if so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Some inconsistency in your question on whether underscores `_` are part of your variable names and where they appear. I've assumed in editing that the real dataset is consistent. Your code block appears to need underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise concrete data example is worth more than a long explanation. Your description seems consistent with an example like this:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1 id float(avar_1 avar_2 avar_3 bvar_1 bvar_2)
"A" 1 . 6 8 10
"B" 2 4 . 9  .
"C" 3 5 7 . 11
end

* 4 is specific to this example. 
rename (bvar_*) (avar_#), renumber(4)

reshape long avar_, i(id) j(which)
(note: j = 1 2 3 4 5)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        3   ->      15
Number of variables                   6   ->       3
j variable (5 values)                     ->   which
xij variables:
               avar_1 avar_2 ... avar_5   ->   avar_
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

drop if missing(avar_)
bysort id (which) : replace which = _n
list, sepby(id)

     +--------------------+
     | id   which   avar_ |
     |--------------------|
  1. |  A       1       1 |
  2. |  A       2       6 |
  3. |  A       3       8 |
  4. |  A       4      10 |
     |--------------------|
  5. |  B       1       2 |
  6. |  B       2       4 |
  7. |  B       3       9 |
     |--------------------|
  8. |  C       1       3 |
  9. |  C       2       5 |
 10. |  C       3       7 |
 11. |  C       4      11 |
     +--------------------+
```

Positive points:

Your data layout cries out for some structure given by a `rename` and especially by a `reshape long`. I don't give here code for a `reshape wide` as for the great majority of Stata purposes, you'd be better off with this layout.

Negative points:

```
!mi(var`x')
```

returns whether the first value of a variable is not missing. If `foo` were a variable in the dataset, `!mi(foo)` is evaluated as `!mi(foo[1])`. That is not what you want here.   See https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/ for the full story.

I'd recommend more evocative variable names.